# Definition of covering spaces: Lee vs Hatcher vs Fulton

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, covering-spaces

Here are three definition of covering spaces/map:

> **Hatcher (AT):** A *covering space* of a space $X$ is a space $Y$
> together with a map $p : Y\to X$ satisfying the following condition: There exists an
> **open cover** $\{U_\alpha\}$
> of $X$ such that for each $\alpha$, $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is a disjoint union of **open sets**
> in $Y$, each of which is mapped by p homeomorphically onto $U_\alpha$. **We do not require
> $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ to be nonempty, so $p$ need not be *surjective*.**

> **Lee (TM):** A *covering map* is a continuous **surjective** map $p : Y\to X$ such that $Y$ is connected
> and locally path-connected, and every point of $X$ has an evenly covered
> neighborhood. (i.e. An
> **open subset** $U\subseteq  X$ is said to be evenly covered by $p$ if $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union
> of connected **open subsets** of $Y$ (called the sheets of the covering over $U$), each of
> which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$.)

> **Fulton (AT):** A *covering map* is a continuous
> mapping $p : Y\to X$ with the property that each point of $X$ has an **open
> neighborhood** $N$ such that $p^{-1}(N)$ is a disjoint union of **open sets**, each
> of which is mapped homeomorphic ally by $p$ onto $N$.

I have highlighted the words that confused me. Are these definitions equivalent? One definition uses opens sets other open neighborhood (I doubt but I think they are identical in this case) And Unlike Lee Hatcher don't require covering map to be surjective. ([See this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2825504/272127))

Are all the above definitions equivalent in the smooth manifolds case?

Comment: I'm confused with Hatcher's definition. If $U_α$ is non empty, then since each slice of $p^{-1} (U_α)$ is homeomorphic to $U_α$ each of these slices must be non empty too. Right?

Comment: I think so. see the linked post there it has been explained.

Comment: This is the comment of Hatcher on his web-page: "The way that $p^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ could be empty is that it could be the union of an empty collection of open sets homeomorphic to $U_{\alpha}$."

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain it to me by an example? I don't understand it.

Comment: This is equivalent to the notion of empty set $φ$ being subset of every set. Why? Because you cannot come up with an element in $φ$ which is not in our set. So even if $p^{-1} (U_α)$ is empty we can take it to be an empty collection of open sets. You cannot come up with an index such that the slice of this index is not homeomorphic to $U_ α$. This I what I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hatcher and Fulton's definitions are the same. Lee's is stricter.
Lee requires $Y$ to be connected. I presume this is because his interest is in manifold
theory.

To see Fulton's and Hatcher's are equivalent, call an open subset $U$ of $X$ good
if $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open sets each mapping homeomorphically to $U$.
Hatcher says that $X$ has a covering of good sets, Fulton that each point of $X$
is contained in a good set. These are the same.

In the Hatcher and Fulton definition, a double cover of $X$ by two copies of $X$
is a covering space. Lee would disallow this, as it is certainly not connected.